# Kubernetes scaledown with high cpuratio

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We're seeing a scaledown triggered on our GKE Autopilot cluster despite the fact that cpuratio is quite high:

```
jsonPayload: {
  decision: {
    decideTime: <snip>
    eventId: <snip>
    scaleDown: {
      nodesToBeRemoved: [
        0: {
          evictedPods: [2]
          evictedPodsTotalCount: 2
          node: {
            cpuRatio: 82
            memRatio: 48
            mig: {3}
            name: <snip>
```

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-down-work utilization should be below 50% to be considered for scaledown so we're wondering why this is happening.

I was wondering if perhaps some system pods come and go changing the CPU, but we have two replicas running there for a total of 3000m CPU out of 3920 allocatable so CPU utilization should never go below 50%.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: There are many factors of a scale down to trigger, CPU utilization is one of the reason. Verify the logs and monitoring metrics for finding the reason for scale down to happen. If possible ping the logs and steps for recreating your cluster.<br>

Comment: Autopilot also uses the [Optimize Utilization Profile](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#autoscaling_profiles)  which targets an 80% utilization rate

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Unfortunately nothing seems to be logged apart from cpu and memory ratio.

Comment: @GariSingh that's an interesting insight, is there any place where those ratios would be documented? The page you linked to doesn't mention that.

Comment: @DawidJanczak - I don't think we do.  I think we only mention that with Optimize Utilization we also set the idle time to 1 minute for node scale down.